# Delphi 2009: Component Object property default value

Tags: class, delphi, properties, components, delphi-2009

How to set the default of a component object property value?

Component Class Code:

```
unit CustomClass;

interface

uses
    Classes;

type
  TCustomClass = class;

  TConfiguration = class;

  TCustomClass = class (TComponent)
  private
    FConfiguration: TConfiguration;
    procedure SetConfiguration(const Value: TConfiguration);
  published
    property Configuration: TConfiguration read FConfiguration write SetConfiguration;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  TConfiguration = class (TPersistent)
  private
    FDelay: Integer;
    FSize: Integer;
    procedure SetDelay(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetSize(const Value: Integer);
  published
    property Delay: Integer read FDelay write SetDelay;
    property Size: Integer read FSize write SetSize;
  public
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
  end;

implementation

{ TCustomClass }

constructor TCustomClass.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Configuration.FileName:= 'FileName';
  Configuration.Size := 10;
end;

destructor TCustomClass.Destroy;
begin
  Configuration.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TCustomClass.SetConfiguration(const Value: TConfiguration);
begin
  FConfiguration.Assign(Value);
end;

{ TConfiguration }

procedure TConfiguration.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
begin
  inherited;
  Delay := (Source as TConfiguration).Delay;
  Size := (Source as TConfiguration).Size;
end;

procedure TConfiguration.SetDelay(const Value: Integer);
begin
  FDelay := Value;
end;

procedure TConfiguration.SetSize(const Value: Integer);
begin
  FSize := Value;
end;

end.
```

In my IDE it will appear as the object property was modified (bold blue).

I thought in making default and stored functions on the TConfiguration class properties, like so:

**TConfiguration**

```
interface

private
  function FileNameStored: Boolean;
published
  property FileName: string read FFileName write SetFileName stored FileNameStored;
  property Size: Integer read FSize write SetSize default 10;

implementation

function TConfiguration.FileNameStored: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FileName <> 'FileName';
end;
```

It colors the properties of TConfiguration in normal blue, but not the Configuration property of TCustomClass and it's not there that I want to set its default values, is on the TCustomClass, since TConfiguration maybe be used in another components.

Then, I also thought:

**TCustomClass**

```
interface

private
  function ConfigurationStored: Boolean;
published
  property Configuration: TConfiguration read FConfiguration write SetConfiguration stored ConfigurationStored;

implementation

function TCustomClass.ConfigurationStored: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Configuration.FileName <> 'FileName' and
    Configuration.Size <> 10;
end;
```

But, this only sets the TCustomClass Configuration property color to normal blue, not its properties.

**ANSWER**

As @RemyLebeau pointed out (in the first and top answer), there were errors in the code.
In that component and that case I decided to not set any default value to the properties.

Comment: Did you intend to drop a configuration object onto a form and also drop the custom class onto a form, and then connect them? Or did you want the configuration object to be a property that belongs to the custom class and does not have to be manually created and assigned?

Comment: Then you really overlooked some obvious things, as Remy points out. He shows you need to explicitly create (in your class constructor) and free (in your class destructor) all TObject-types that belong to (are an indivisible part of) your object. You had the base class correct, so that's good. You may want to add an OnChange:TNotificationEvent to your configuration object.  So it can call the main class and have it do something when someone writes to a configuration property.

Comment: @WarrenP Yes. I fixed it, but as @NGLN pointed out, doesn't makes sense correcting it on the question, since it turns the answer unnecessary. The `OnChange: TNotificationEvent` is really a good advice, I liked it, since I can change the `stored` value of properties if they are a class private variable. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several bugs in your code.

1. your `TCustomClass` constructor is not creating the `TConfiguration` object.  You need to add that:

   ```
   constructor TCustomClass.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
   begin
     inherited;
     FConfiguration := TConfiguration.Create; // <-- add this
     FConfiguration.FileName := 'FileName';
     FConfiguration.Size := 10;
   end;
   ```

   That being said, the assignment of the `FileName` and `Size` properties should probably be moved to the `TConfiguration` constructor rather than `TCustomClass` constructor.
2. A `String` property cannot be defined with a user-defined default value, the default is always a blank string.  So your `FileName` property will always appear as modified when your component is created, because your constructor is assigning a non-default value to it.  Your `stored` approach is the correct solution to handle that.  Or, simply do not assign a default `FileName at all`, leave it blank.  If the user does not assign an explicit `FileName`, your code could assume a default value if needed.

   An `Integer` property, on the other hand, can be defined with a user-defined default value.  Your `Size` property is not doing that, though.  It should be (especially if you move the assignment of the default value into the `TConfiguration` constructor):

   ```
   property Size: Integer read FSize write SetSize default 10;
   ```
3. your `TConfiguration.Assign()` method is implemented incorrectly.  By calling the inherited `Assign()` method before copying values, your code will always raise an `EConvertError` exception at runtime if the caller assigns one `TConfiguration` object to another.  The reason is because the base class `TPersistent.Assign()` implementation simply calls `Source.AssignTo(Self)`, and `TConfiguration` does not override the `AssignTo()` method, so `TPersistent.AssignTo()` gets called, which simply calls `Dest.AssignError(Self)`, which raises the exception.  So, DO NOT call the inherited `Assign()` method if the `Source` is actually a `TConfiguration` object:

   ```
   procedure TConfiguration.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
   begin
     if Source is TConfiguration then
     begin
       FDelay := TConfiguration(Source).Delay;
       FSize := TConfiguration(Source).Size;
     end else
       inherited;
   end;
   ```

Comment: Why should I move the TConfiguration assignment from the TCustomClass constructor to the TConfiguration constructor? Is it a conventional way when writing components classes? Because what do I do if in the future I create another component and utilize that same TConfiguration class?

Comment: A class' property is a characteristic of that class. A default value of that property too. That's enough reason already. But especially when you need to use that class in multiple scenarios, you should design it to be capable of behaving autonomous. Thus you create a `TConfiguration` in the class where you need it, and there you possibly assign custom settings, but the default settings are made within `TConfiguration` itself.

Comment: That's completely up to you. If a green apple needs to be red in a fruit basket, then make it red while filling the basket. But if a green apple should have red spots, then you should design a spotted apple capable of having spots before making the basket. Or: if it doesn't matter which type of banana the basket holds, then register the banana type after filling the basket. But when there only may be Chiquita bananas in the basket, then enforce that restriction by designing a TChiquitaBanana from TBanana specifically for this type of basket.

Answer (score 0):

> But, this only sets the `TCustomClass` `Configuration` property color to normal blue, not its properties.

That is by design. A [storage specifier](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Determining_What_to_Store) only works for the property it is specified for.

Compare you class with a `TFont` property on a form. When `ParentFont` is `True`, the `Font` property will not be stored. But its members `Color` and `Name` still are not default, thus they appear as if they will be stored. This is because a `TFont` object does not know about its owner, how could it? One time it is part of a canvas, the other time it is part of a control, or has no owner at all. In all these conditions, the `TFont` object should be fully functional, so it does not enquiry its parent how it should behave. On the other side: the parent should not enquiry its child on how to behave too.

Now back to your scenario: whether `FileName` and `Size` properties need to be stored should be dealt with in `TConfiguration`. Whether the `Configuration` property of `TCustomClass` should be stored may *not* depend on these `FileName` and `Size` properties. If the `Configuration` property is stored (is bold), but all its members are not stored (not bold), then nothing is stored in the end. If you have a `ParentConfiguration` property, alike `ParentFont`, thén you can deside not to store the `Configuration` property. Otherwise, leave it be and let the boldness not distract you any further.

Comment: Your words are true.
But in that citation I tried to explain that the 'stored' 'Configuration' property approach ins't enough to satisfy my needs because it only makes 'Configuration' normal blue and not its properties - that will stay greyed blue.